# An easy-to-use tool to copy data from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob/ADLS Gen2 via Azure Data Factory

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-explorer

Is there any simple tool to help me copy data from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob or Azure Data Lake Gen2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Data Factory team recently built a storage explorer extension, which is used to copy data from Amazon s3 to Azure Blob or Azure Data Lake Gen2 with simple drag and drop.
Check it here:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/main/StorageExplorerExtension/storage-explorer-plugin.md

Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=GacGa5T0flk